# Помощь в разработке простой игры на JavaFX (Xonix)

Tags: java, javafx, разработка-игр

Всем привет. Нужна помощь в создании игры. Хочу сделать игру Xonix. Есть класс с "персонажем". Теперь есть потребность в том, что нужно сделать движок. Суть игры в том, что есть поле. В этом поле есть 2 врага, которые двигаются от грани до грани. Есть игрок. И игроку нужно обрезать часть этого поля так, чтобы на путь игрока не попали враги (аналогия со змейкой, нельзя касаться своего пути, только здесь враги не должны тронуть твой путь). Теперь проблема в том, что нет идей, как реализовать вот это "вырезание" поля. [image: Это примерный геймплей игры]

А это код персонажа (обычный квадратик).

```
public static class GameUnit extends Rectangle implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

    public GameUnit(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);

    }

    private void checkInitBehavior() {
        if (behavior == null) {
            behavior = new GameUnitBehavior();
            new Thread(behavior).start();
        }
    }

    private GameUnitBehavior behavior;

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        checkInitBehavior();
        switch (event.getCode()) {
            case LEFT:
                behavior.moveToSide(Side.LEFT);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                behavior.moveToSide(Side.RIGHT);
                break;
            case UP:
                behavior.moveToSide(Side.TOP);
                break;
            case DOWN:
                behavior.moveToSide(Side.BOTTOM);
                break;
        }
    }

    private class GameUnitBehavior extends Task {

        private boolean vertical = false;

        private boolean positiv = false;

        private double step = 10.0;

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            while (getScene().getWindow().isShowing()) {
                if (vertical) {
                    setX(getX() + (positiv ? step : -step));
                } else {
                    setY(getY() + (positiv ? step : -step));
                }
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void moveToSide(Side side) {
            vertical = side.isVertical();
            positiv = side == (vertical ? Side.RIGHT : Side.BOTTOM);
        }
    }
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJCbKPNEnF8 ЭТО ВИДЕО С ГЕЙМПЛЕЕМ

Comment: Я думаю, вам придется поподробнее рассказать о том, что значит обрезать (как это должно выглядеть) . Я лично совсем не понял суть игры. Если суть не будет понятна, то и ответов вы вряд ли получите.

Comment: Если есть точно такая игра или подобие, то запишите видео и добавьте ссылку. А в самом крайнем случае, включите запись с экрана, рисуйте последовательность игры в Painte и озвучьте.

Comment: @Turalllb https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJCbKPNEnF8 Вот так она должна выглядеть)

Comment: Первые мысли на сонную голову: Есть поле с Границами, границы будут меняться. Когда персонаж выходит в поле и касается после этого вновь границу   ( и в это время его линию движения не пересекает враг) , то граница поля меняется. Ну это так , самый верхний слой алгоритма))

Comment: Где то конкурс проходит?) (4 дня назад был задан аналогичный вопрос)